# Changing wrapping tags and keeping content inside tags with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regex I am trying to change these p tags be wrapped in a ul tag and converted to li items. I have the below regex to target the specific class and grab whatever content is inside the p tag. But it doesnt look to playing ball. Any direction would be great.

```
html = html.replace(/<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst">(.*?)<\/p>/, '<ul><li>$1</li>');
html = html.replace(/<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle">(.*?)<\/p>/, '<li>$1</li>');
html = html.replace(/<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpLast">(.*?)<\/p>/, '<li>$1</li><ul>');
```

Current mark up below

```
<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst">Item 1</p>
<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle">Item 2</p>
<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpLast">Item 3</p>
```

Desired mark up below

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Depending on input, could also use just one replace, something [like this](https://tio.run/##jY5BC4IwGEDv/orhZWrlqC5Bcx2CIFAIOrbCacMWXzq2Jf1705CO0f29x7uLVtjSKO1m7arrQDp0cw9ACcqpRiUIaxM/s02qrDsIIyoj9G37OuqdMtb5bO/kA80p0cz7zWfqegU5Cos/hFR8@8sBz9eeN65h@gTGa4wmn9nYSA2ilAHhheYFt9Hpwug5CjYJC0k1RRgUDnsY85qSXsV9qmxq24CMoamCIRKuu@4N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the slash `/` in the`ul` closing tag.

```js
let html = document.body.innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst">(.*?)<\/p>/, '<ul><li>$1</li>');
html = html.replace(/<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle">(.*?)<\/p>/, '<li>$1</li>');
html = html.replace(/<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpLast">(.*?)<\/p>/, '<li>$1</li></ul>');

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst">Item 1</p>
<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle">Item 2</p>
<p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpLast">Item 3</p>
```